# Discourse SES AWS working app.yml file example please

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses, discourse

Can someone please post an AWS SES working app.yml file example? I mean literally copy and paste it. Been fighting this set up for days and its got to be something minor in the config settings.

Comment: figured it out. See example below for SMTP settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587 DISCOURSE_SMTP_DOMAIN: mail.<yourmaildomain>.com 
DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: <SMTP USER NAME>
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: <SMTP USER PW>
DISCOURSE_SMTP_AUTHENTICATION: "login" 
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ENABLE_START_TLS: true # (optional, default true) 
DISCOURSE_SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE: none
```

Answer (score 1):

discourse v 1.9.1

/discourse/htdocs/config/discourse.conf

```
smtp_address = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
smtp_port = 587
smtp_domain = your_domain.com
smtp_user_name = username # from AWS SMTP Settings/Create my Credentials
smtp_password = password # from AWS SMTP Settings/Create my Credentials
smtp_enable_start_tls = true
smtp_authentication= "login"
SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE = "none"
smtp_from_address = # aws verified address
```

Must have requested limit increase from AWS - in Support Center.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the settings posted by [Richard Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346269), I think you also need to enable this line in `app.yml` and change the email address with the validated email address in SES:

```
- exec: rails r "SiteSetting.notification_email='info@unconfigured.discourse.org'"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628070/6738855) for more details.