# Discourse email configuration for AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, discourse

I'm trying to get Discourse set up on an AWS EC2 instance, but am having problems getting the emails to send via AWS SES.

Firstly I have an email and a domain set up and confirmed (not in sandbox mode) on AWS SES and I can successfully send test emails from the AWS SES dashboard, and also manually through postfix running on the Discourse machine instance.

I have attempted to follow instructions here: http://stroupaloop.com/blog/discourse-setup-using-aws/ (though realise this is quite old now, so perhaps the config is different now) and also found [Discourse SES AWS working app.yml file example please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345752/discourse-ses-aws-working-app-yml-file-example-please) - but this config isn't working for me either.

For info, I'm editing the app.yml file by doing....

```
$ sudo ./launcher stop app
$ sudo nano ./containers/app.yml
```

[making the edits and saving]

```
$ sudo ./launcher bootstrap app
```

[it tells me it has bootstrapped correctly]

```
$ sudo ./launcher start app
```

[I can now view the discourse site, but can;t login to any accounts as the confirmation emails aren't getting sent]

Currently I have this in my app.yml file (sensitive info replaced):

```
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_ENABLE_START_TLS: true           
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_AUTHENTICATION: "login"
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_OPENSSL_VERIFY_MODE: none
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_DOMAIN: mydomain.net
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_FROM_ADDRESS: me@mydomain.net
```

Also, in the SES sending stats dashboard, I'm not even seeing that it's trying to send the email.

So even a good starting point would be to know if there is an email log file somewhere in the Discourse docker container that I can look at to see what the issue may be.

Any help on where I'm going wrong here would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you please share logs from discourse if there are any email related.
you can find logs from discourse using URL: yourdiscoursedomain.com/logs

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by editing `app.yml` and adding this line towards the end (the line is commented out by default):

```
- exec: rails r "SiteSetting.notification_email='info@unconfigured.discourse.org'"
```

You must replace `info@unconfigured.discourse.org` with the validated email address associated with your SES credentials. You can check your validated email address identities under AWS -> SES -> Identity Management -> Email Addresses, the Verification Status must be verified. If you managed to send and receive a test email from here, you probably have this already set up.

Once you have applied these changes, re-run the setup script to pick up the changes:

```
sudo ./discourse-setup
```

Hope this works at your end!

Answer (score 1):

I had my discourse deployed in ec2 using bitnami and after trying for hours I was able to configure SES sandbox with discourse heres what I did

1. created SMTP credentials in the aws console
2. I verified two emails in aws console, since the email service was in sandbox so both sender and receiver emails have to be verified
3. I added smtp settings to this file `/apps/discourse/htdocs/config/discourse.conf` which looked like this

```
db_name = bitnami_discourse
db_host = /opt/bitnami/postgresql
db_port = 5432
db_pool = 25
hostname = 3.89.1xx.xx
db_username = bn_discourse
db_password = “xxxxxxxxxx”
redis_port = 6379
redis_path = /opt/bitnami/redis/var/run/redis.sock

smtp_address =“email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com”
smtp_port = 587
smptp_security = ssl
smtp_domain = 3.89.1xx.xx
smtp_user_name = ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’
smtp_password = ‘xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx’
from_address = youremailaddress@example.com
```

The smptp username and password are the same SMTP credentials you obtain in step 1 after you configured this file make sure to restart the server by running this command outside of /apps

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

heres a [reference](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/use-ses/)